# In Typescript is it possible to check the correctnes of the return object type of a generic function?

Tags: json, typescript, validation, prisma, typechecking

I'm trying to understand if there is a way to validate the result of JSON.parse for different possible type.
In the APIs I'm working on there are a lot of Json fields coming from the database that should be made with specific structures, so I would like to check if a certain JsonValue returned from database is coherent with a given type.

I've made a bit of different tries, this is how I've defined the generic funcion:

```
parseJsonField<T>(jsonValue: Prisma.JsonValue): T {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonValue));
}
```

I'd like to have something that throws an error when the jsonValue has not the exact properties of the type T, but this is not working.

I'm testing with this class

```
export class ProgramTagsDTO {
  key: string;
  value: string;

  constructor(key: string, value: string) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

When I run this test:

```
it('should validate', () => {
  const tags: Prisma.JsonValue = [
    {
      key: 'key1',
      value: 'value1',
      wrongField: 'value',
    },
    {
      key: 'key2',
      value: 'value2',
    },
  ];
  let result = null;
  const expectedResult = [
    new ProgramTagsDTO('key1', 'value1'),
    new ProgramTagsDTO('key2', 'value2'),
  ];
  try {
    result = programmesService.parseJsonField<ProgramTagsDTO[]>(tags);
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(Error);
  }
  expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
});
```

I get:

```
 expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 2
    + Received  + 3

      Array [
    -   ProgramTagsDTO {
    +   Object {
          "key": "key1",
          "value": "value1",
    +     "wrongField": "value",
        },
    -   ProgramTagsDTO {
    +   Object {
          "key": "key2",
          "value": "value2",
        },
      ]
```

But this is not what I want, I would like to make the method throw an exception. (the expect.toEqual is just to see the log)

Comment: There is no way to verify at compile time the results of JSON.parse. You might want to try a schema validator like Joi or Zod

Comment: I will check for them, thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some days of tries me and a coworker came up with this solution that for now seems to work well:

Adding this import:

```
import { ClassConstructor, plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';
```

We made 2 methods for array and single values:

```
public static async parseJsonArray<T>(
  cls: ClassConstructor<T>,
  json: Prisma.JsonValue,
): Promise<T[]> {
  if (!Array.isArray(json)) {
    throw new UnprocessableEntityException(
      `Json value is not a ${cls.name}[]`,
    );
  }
  const res: Promise<T>[] = [];
  for (const element of json) {
    res.push(this.parseJsonValue<T>(cls, element));
  }
  return Promise.all(res);
}

public static async parseJsonValue<T>(
  cls: ClassConstructor<T>,
  json: Prisma.JsonValue,
): Promise<T> {
  const parsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
  const transformed: T = plainToClass(cls, parsed, {
    excludeExtraneousValues: true,
  });
  return validate(transformed as object).then((errors) => {
    if (errors.length) {
      throw new UnprocessableEntityException(
        `Json value is not a ${cls.name}, Errors: ${errors}`,
      );
    }
    return transformed;
  });
}
```

plainToClass handles array, but we need to have something generic the returns clearly array or a single object based on what you are parsing, so it was not possible to have a single method with return signature like T | T[].

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. Like in many languages (for example, Java), the generics are removed when the code gets compiled. In Typescript it's even worse, the 'types' get removed, meaning that it transpiles to javascript, which is weakly typed.

So, once at runtime, the following code:

```
parseJsonField<T>(jsonValue: Prisma.JsonValue): T {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonValue));
}
```

gets reduced to:

```
parseJsonField(jsonValue) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonValue));
}
```

So, there is no type information to check.

Moreover, you're using a class, beware that even if you could be able to check that the returned value adheres to the interface of `T`, it would not be an *instance* of `T`, but merely a generic object happening to have properties with the same name as an instance of `T` would.

You must implement checks at runtime. Similar to your solution posted above, you could generalize it:

```
// Gets a value and deletes it from the json object
function getDelete<T>(jsonValue :any, property :string, required = false) :T {
  const ret = jsonValue[property];
  delete jsonValue[property];
  if (required && typeof ret === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error(`Property ${property} not found`);
  }
  return ret;
}

// Checks that the json object is empty, otherwise there are extraneous values
function checkEmpty(jsonValue: any) {
  if (Object.keys(jsonValue).length > 0) {
    throw new Error('Object contains extraneous properties ' + JSON.stringify(jsonValue));
  }
}

// Example of a class
public class Person {
  private firstName :string;
  private lastName :string;

  constructor(jsonValue? :any) {
    if (jsonValue) {
      // This is where we "parse" the json object into the actual class, and check it
      this.firstName = getDelete(jsonValue, 'firstName');
      this.lastName = getDelete(jsonValue, 'lastName');
    }
    checkEmpty(jsonValue);
  }
}


function parseAndCheck<T>(jsonValue :any, constructor: (...arg: any[])=>T) :T {
  return constructor(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonValue)));
}
```

(haven't tested the code above, just to give you an idea)